# Close tab created by Window.open() in Window class derived from JavaScriptObject in GWT

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I need to close a 'tab' that is created by a class derived from JavaScriptObject, using GWT.
Here's a code snippet:-

```
public class MyWindow extends JavaScriptObject {
    // All types that extend JavaScriptObject must have a protected,
    // no-args constructor. 
    protected MyWindow() {}

    public static native MyWindow open(String url, String target, String options) /*-{
      return $wnd.open(url, target, options);
    }-*/;

    public static final native void close() /*-{
      this.close();
    }-*/;

    public static final native void setUrl(String url) /*-{
      if (this.location) {
        this.location = url;
      }
    }-*/;
}

public class MyUsingClass {
    // Have to have my own window object derived from JavaScriptObject.
    // Cannot use standard Window, because we are in an async callback,
    // and browser thinks it's a popup!
    MyWindow myWindow = MyWindow.open(null, "_blank", null);
    ...
    @Override
    public void registeredCallback(ArrayList<String> params)
    {
       ...
       // The URL passed to setUrl, is a call to a servlet that returns a 
       // response with Content-Disposition set in the header.
       // We get a File SaveAs Dialog box displayed, 'owned', I assume, by
       // this.myWindow.
       myWindow.setUrl(url);
       ...
    }
```

The problem I have, is that the Dialog Box runs as expected, and closes on Ok or Cancel button getting pressed, however, I cannot figure out how [and where/when] to close the tab that is created by the call to MyWindow.open().
I'm guessing that I, somehow, need to catch an event triggered by the File SaveAs Dialog closing?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to open new tab (window) just to have save file dialog. I use current window and (when I'm sure the file is accessible) I just do:

```
Window.Location.assign(__file_servlet_path__);
```

In the servlet I set `Content-type` and `Content-disposition` header:

```
resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + __file_name__ + "\"");
```

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response. Tried using Window.Location.assign() in place of MyWindow.open() and all works as required!
Absolutely beautiful, easy fix ... Thank You!!